# Use images form camera without taking a photo

Tags: iphone, image-processing

Is it possible to analyze the images without taking a foto on the iPhone ?

I want to analyze some matrix codes, without taking any foto. I saw this on some Nokia models and it's quite impressive: really fast!

On the iPhone, I've seen analyzing codes after taking a snapshot (or photo), and it's slower.

Also the iPhone camera is not good as some other mobile cameras.

I'm refering to iPhone 3G/3GS.

thanks,

r.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Under iOS 4.x, you can use the new [AVFoundation Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/Introduction/Introduction.html) to access camera pixel buffers on the 3G and 3GS, as well as the newer iPhone 4, without taking a photo/snapshot.  The newer devices have higher resolution camera's.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible. But I think you should take a look at the AVCamDemo Apple's Code from de WWDC 2010. I think it could help you even if I didn't read a lot of code (juste compiled tje xCode project and tried it)
(Sorry but I can't find back the link)

You should be able to find the code in your emails if you are registred as an iPhone Developer. Or maybe on the [developer.apple.com/iphone/](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/) website.

By the way, don't think doing it on iPhone 3G (impossible I think). The iPhone 3GS should be fast enough for this kind of app.

Good Luck !

Comment: I can't find the AVCamDemo demo in the developer.apple.com/iphone registered area. Maybe has some other name ?

Comment: You should get it by downloading sample code at this url : http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/ Just Open iTunes with the link in this page and search for the pack of codes :-)